# Starting docker-compose via npm

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a small node app against which I want to run some browsertests.
I am wondering what the best approach was.
First I was thinking to put everything in my `package.json` but I do not see how I would spin up docker-compose, run the tests, and kill docker-compose.

For example, I would make something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "docker-compose up && mocha --ui tdd test/**/*.test.js --reporter spec && docker-compose down
```

But I am not sure that this is possible.

What is used nowadays to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Could you elaborate please?  "put everything in my package.json" is a little vague.  You can certainly `docker-compose up -d` `docker-compose run foo` (or `docker run foo`) `docker-compose down`.  They can even be separate npm tasks that chain together.  What did you try and what is not working for you?

Comment: @Wyck added some extra info.

Comment: Did you try it and run into problems?  `docker-compose up` is blocking whereas `docker-compose up -d` will return and allow mocha to run.

Comment: @Wyck yes, but mocha starts running the tests before all my services are up and running

Comment: Synchronization is a part of it.  You'll have to code that manually (retry if server isn't available) or read and use a pre-made solution like https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2016/10/17/docker-compose-wait-for-dependencies.html  Is that the only problem you're having?

Comment: @Wyck currently that is the only problem, yes. Probably not the last one. I'll try your link and maybe head back here if it goes tits up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a synchronization issue where your tests try to access services before your test fixture has reached the point where the services are available.  (It may be something like a node app with an HTTP server that listens for API requests, for example.)

When you do `docker-compose up -d`, the docker-compose process exits before the containerized services within have created their sockets and started listening for connections.  That means that if the next thing you do is run your tests that try to open a connection to the services started by docker-compose, there is a race condition where the service may not be available yet.

You'll have to make your test so that when it tries to open a connection, if it encounters a timeout, then it retries a few times (allowing enough time and retries for your containers to reach a state where they are listening and ready to service requests before giving up.)

You can usually just have a simple standalone app that repeatedly tries to open up the service port and returns success when it succeeds (or retries if it times out up to some maximum where it returns an error).  Insert this before you run your tests to ensure your services have reached a listening state.

I strongly suggest reading [Docker Compose: Wait for Dependencies](https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2016/10/17/docker-compose-wait-for-dependencies.html)

That article describes a nice little docker-image you can use that will repeatedly try to open a TCP port until it succeeds.  You can use it to synchronize your test with the test fixture services the test requires.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but the next thing you will encounter is orphaning the test fixture when the tests fail.  For that you'll need some kind of _try-finally_ that will ensure that the `docker-compose down` always runs, even when the tests fail.  Also, you'll likely want `--remove-orphans` too and other nuances.